# Access to CloudKit databases from a Mac?

Tags: ios, osx-yosemite, cloudkit

I'd like to experiment with using CloudKit to access my data from an iOS application. Ideally, I'd like to consume this data from my iOS application but to produce it and save it from a Mac application.

Has anyone seen anything suggesting the ability to access CloudKit databases from Mac OS or  is this an iOS-only framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CloudKit is definitely available on OS X, but only in Yosemite (10.10). You can download the Yosemite beta and SDK from Apple's developer site - the framework is identical on iOS and OS X, so you should be able to share most of your code.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification: I had looked in the documentation and not see it in the Mac OS X version at first, but now I see that it is documented both for iOS 8 and for OS X Yosemite.

Answer (score 0):

Also, as the developer of an app, you can use the **CloudKit Dashboard** to upload records to the public database, even on a productive environment.